# Sound Sculptures & Installations

Tags: sound-installations, design

I guess this might interest many of you guys so i put the link bellow!

http://www.tsimpountiii.gr/en/technology-tech/sound-sculptures-installations/

Comment: That guy is a hero of mine.  Texture beyond measure.

Comment: That's fantastic!